# Wordpress | Template | category-id.php | Display a list of posts with links

Tags: wordpress, while-loop, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating category templates (by ID).  Within each category template I need to display a list of the posts titles (with their link).

The code I am using (below) is not working.  I have checked the variable using an echo an it is pulling in the correct ID number so I am assuming the fault lies with the WHILE loop.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:justify;">
<table class="table table-striped">

    <?php

    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;                            

    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '70', 'orderby' =>
    'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) ); 

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    echo '<tr><td><a href="';

    the_permalink();

    echo '">';

    the_title();

    echo '</a></td></tr>';

    endwhile;

    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is "not working"? Do you get the wrong posts? no posts at all? note that you are not using the variable in your query.

Comment: You're not passing `$cat_id` to anything...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cat_id  = get_query_var('cat');
$showposts = 10;
$args = array('cat' => $cat_id, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => $showposts,'post_status' => 'publish');
query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>      
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <?php _e('No Posts Sorry.'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Would you please try above code?